# Generalization of the product formula on subfactors

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, subfactors, planar-algebras

The [product formula](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Product_formula) on finite groups states that for $H_1, H_2$ subgroups of $G$, then 
$$ |H_1H_2| \cdot |H_1 \cap H_2|=|H_1| \cdot |H_2| $$
This statement could be generalized to any finite index irreducible subfactor planar algebra $\mathcal{P}$ by:
For any biprojection $b_1, b_2 \in \mathcal{P}_{2,+}$, then
$$ tr(S(b_1 * b_2)) \cdot tr(b_1 \wedge b_2)=tr(b_1) \cdot tr(b_2) $$
with $(\_ * \_)$ the coproduct, $S(\_)$ the range support, and $tr(\_)$ the normalized trace.

*Question*: Is this generalization true?

---

Note that $tr(b_1 * b_2) = \delta tr(b_1)tr(b_2)$, with $\delta^{-2} = tr(e_1)$ and $e_1$ the trivial biprojection.

Comment: A result of Zeph Landau states that $b_1∗b_2=\delta tr(b_1b_2)S(b_1∗b_2)$ (see Theorem 3.10 [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2007-20-01/S0894-0347-06-00531-5/S0894-0347-06-00531-5.pdf)). It follows that $tr(S(b_1∗b_2))tr(b_1b_2)=tr(b_1)tr(b_2)$.

Comment: Before that, see Sano-Watatani [paper](http://jot.theta.ro/jot/archive/1994-032-002/1994-032-002-001.pdf), Remark p235.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to generalize the equation. I give two different ones here:

(1) In terms of bimodules: Take a finite index irreducible subfactor $N \subset M$. Suppose $P_1$ and $P_2$ are two intermediate subfactors and $P=P_1 \cap P_2$. Then we have the following equation for $N-N$ bimodules:
$$\dim(P_1\mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}\limits_{P}} P_2)\dim(P)=\dim(P_1)\dim(P_2).$$

Proof: \begin{align*}
\dim(P_1)\dim(P_2)&=\dim(P_1\mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}\limits_{N}}P_2)\\
&=\dim(P_1\mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}\limits_{P}}P\mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}\limits_{N}}P\mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}\limits_{P}}P_2)\\
&=\dim(P_1\mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}\limits_{P}} P_2)\dim(P\mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}\limits_{P}}P)\\
&=\dim(P_1\mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}\limits_{P}} P_2)\dim(P).
\end{align*}

When $M=N\rtimes G$, $P_i=N\rtimes H_i$, for $i=1,2$, one obtains the group case.

(2) In terms of two boxes in planar algebras: 
We have an inequality in your formulation.

Proof: Let $b,b_1,b_2$ be biprojections corresponding to $P,P_1,P_2$ in case (1).
Then 
\begin{align*}
tr(S(b_1*b_2))&=\dim(P_1P_2)\leq\dim(P_1\mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}\limits_{N}}P_2);\\
tr(b)&=\dim(P);\\
tr(b_1)&=\dim(P_1);\\
tr(b_2)&=\dim(P_2).
\end{align*}
By the equation in case (1), we have that
$$tr(S(b_1*b_2))tr(b)\leq tr(b_1)tr(b_2).$$
The equality holds iff $b_1b_2=b$. This condition always holds for commutative algebras, but not for non-commutative algebras.

Instead we can prove the following equality using the exchange relation of biprojections.
$$tr(S(b_1*b_2))tr(b_1b_2)=tr(b_1)tr(b_2).$$
(I used this formula to show that the lower bound of the angle between minimal biprojections is $60^\circ$.)

Comment: An interesting corollary is that if two biprojections $b_1$ and $b_2$ bicommute (i.e. $b_1b_2 = b_2b_1$ and $b_1 * b_2 = b_2 * b_1$) then $|b_1 \vee b_2 : b_1| = |b_2 : b_1 \wedge b_2|$.